# SSIS and missing cr lf in row

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm having an issue with SSIS.  Its really throwing things off.  Here is an example of what I am facing

```
H~Column1~Column2~Column3~Column4
D~1~2~3~4<LF>
D~6-7-8-9<LF>
T~ More Stuff<LF>
```

The first line doesn't have an LF character so when I set up a File Task in SSIS, the program reads it as 1 column as one long string

```
H~Column1~Column2~Column3~Column4D~1~2~3~4D~6-7-8-9T~ More Stuff
```

Any idea on how to break this up so that SSIS can delimit this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Script task to read the whole file line-by-line and output it to a new file caled {YourFilename}_Cleaned (or something like that).  Below is a skeleton of the Main() method.  Just replace the comment "// insert LF into LineData after column name list" with the code to insert the LF at the correct point in your first line.

```
/* include these
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
*/


// put the below in your Main() method
string sourceFile = (string)Dts.Variables["FilePickupRootPath"].Value + "\\Process\\" + (string)Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value;
            string cleanFile = (string)Dts.Variables["FilePickupRootPath"].Value + "\\Process\\" + (string)Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value + "_Cleaned";
            string lineData;
            Boolean isFirstLine = true;

            try
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sourceFile);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cleanFile, false);
                lineData = reader.ReadLine();
                while (lineData != null)
                {
                    if (isFirstLine)
                    {
                        // insert LF into LineData after column name list
                        isFirstLine = false;
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine(lineData);
                    lineData = reader.ReadLine();
                }
                reader.Close();
                writer.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error!");
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```